# Interpretation of order of vanishing of Modular L-function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, l-functions

The BSD conjecture gives an interpretation to the order of vanishing of the central value the L-function of an elliptic curve (it is supposed to be the rank of that elliptic curve), while the modularity theorem says that any such L-function is actually the L-function of some Hecke modular form.

Has there been work on the meaning of the order of vanishing of a central value of the L-function of a Hecke eigenform in this other context (other than the straightforward ones about the magnitude of the coefficients)?

Comment: There's BSD for abelian varieties.  If you mean beyond this, probably that question is better suited for MO.

Comment: You could be after the Bloch-Kato conjecture, which is very general, but in the case of modular forms, relates the order of vanishing of the $L$-function of $f$ at the central value, to the rank of the so called Bloch-Kato Selmer group, defined in terms of the Galois representation associated to $f$. When $f$ comes from an elliptic curve, this conjecture generalises the rank part of the BSD conjecture.

Comment: Most major progress towards BSD (Gross-Zagier, Kolyvagin, Kato) has come from the relationship with modular forms! It's also worth remembering that the BSD conjecture only actually makes sense for modular elliptic curves! We need modularity to prove analytic condition, so without it, we have know way of knowing that $L(E, s)$ is even defined at $s=1$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 your last comment is about the *general* case of $L(E,s)$ for elliptic curves over $\mathbf Q$, not every specific case. Analytic continuation of $L(E,s)$ to $s = 1$ (or to all of $\mathbf C$) was known in some specific cases long before the modularity theorem, since after all Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer were led to their conjecture by working with CM elliptic curves over $\mathbf Q$, whose $L$-functions could be expressed in terms of $L$-functions of Hecke characters, which already had a known analytic continuation to $\mathbf C$.

Comment: @KCd Thanks for the correction! I do of course mean the general case. Although, in the CM case, modularity was known to Shimura et al, long before Wiles!